# Gmail Api gives user rate limit exceeded error

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, gmail-api

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 429 Too Many Requests
{
  "code" : 429,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2020-08-25T06:45:05.452Z",
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2020-08-25T06:45:05.452Z",
  "status" : "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
}
```

This error is continuously coming in our production system where we read support emails and store them in our database. Because of this issue, we are unable to store customer complaints in our platform.

```
2020-08-25T06:45:05.452Z
```

The above time is 9 hrs from now and I can't afford that long delay as well.
On the cloud console, the api quota limit hasn't exceeded and I don't know where to check user limits.

Here is my cloud quota usage

[image]

Comment: I am afraid there is nothing we can do about it. Have you tried to contact Google?

Comment: I actually don't have a support plan

Comment: You probably hit the 'Queries per minute per user' limit. As the screenshot shows the others to be within limit. But contact Google, or you are stuck waiting for 9 hours.

Comment: BTW this error is only happening for one email Id. For the rest of the email ids connected to the app, it works fine

Comment: Just a hint, saying "Extremely urgent" and "I actually don't have a support plan" are not a good combination.

Comment: Sorry for that, my company is now talking to google for potential solutions. We got the support plan finally

Answer (score 0):

> 429 Too Many Requests

Means that you have hit one of the daily quota limits. There are limits as to how many requests your project can make per day.  This limit will reset at midnight west cost usa time.

You should increase your quota or apply for a quota extension this will depend upon the API you are using.

There is nothing you can do once you hit this quota you will need to wait for it to reset and make fewer requests tomrrow.

If you go to the [Google developer console.](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/gmail.googleapis.com/quotas?) there are better graphs that will show what your project has been doing.

[image]

Comment: Can you check the image I attached too? I haven't actually hit the limit of 1,000,000,000

Comment: I did check your image.  I suspect you check your code google is not lieing when they lock you out for using the API to much.   You made to many requests.   I would wait until tomrrow and check the Google developer console what your application has been doing the graph should be updated then.  google is very strict with regard to Gmail api requests due to previous spamming issues.

Comment: That graph shows around 120,000 requests for today. Don't know if it's updated to the last minute or not

Comment: It will be interesting to see if you get locked out tomorrow when you hit 120,000 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has nothing to do with quota settings, but with the fact you can only send 2000 emails a day.
That's why it tells you to wait until specified daytime.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en

And here it says only 1500 recipients/day:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas